# How to send ether from a smart contract address to another address?

Tags: payable, sendtransaction

I have a contract that I can deposit ethers by using a `fallback` function. The question is, I want to send the ethers **INSIDE THIS** smart contract to another random address.
I am not asking to send ethers from one address to another. I am asking to send ethers in this contract to another address. Or the same question in other words: How can i send the ethers inside this smart contract to any address I want(without using `selfdestruct`).

function foo is sending ether from function caller address to the target address (`_to`). That is not what I want. I want send ethers inside this contract to the target address(`_to`). Do you have any idea how to do this?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.7;

contract TestCall {

    fallback() external payable{}

    function foo(address payable _to) external payable{
        (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "transaction failed");
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good IMO, but I would do that instead:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.7;

contract TestCall {

    fallback() external payable{}

    function foo(address payable _to, uint256 amount) external payable{
        (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "transaction failed");
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

With msg.value, you will need to include a *value* in the transaction you're sending to the contract and this value will be sent afterwards to the address you set. This is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general function to withdraw full contract balance to any address.

```
function withDraw(address payable to) public payable OnlyOwner {
        uint Balance = address(this).balance;
        require(Balance > 0 wei, "Error! No Balance to withdraw"); 
        to.transfer(Balance);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can include the transfer in the fallback function

```
    address payable extContract;

    fallback() external payable{
        extContract.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

So when anybody sends eth to this contract, it is forwarded to another address.
(Have not checked if this exceeds the gas limit for fallback functions)